# Информирование пользователя о тиках таймера в десктопном приложении

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vb.net

Имеется программа с формой и двумя таймерами.

**Ситуация 1:**
Один таймер срабатывает раз в секунду и выполняет запрос на сервер для получения информации. Точность данного таймера не очень важна. Необходимо отобразить визуально на форме что произошло обновление даннных или что произошел тик таймера.
Например каким нибудь мигающим знаком, мигнул и до следующего тика не отображается. Пытался делать анимацию сменой цвета какого то текста на лейбле, с задержкой через `Thread.Sleep(300)` что собственно вызвало проблему (мигание элемента не стабильной частоты из за того что происходит смещение вызова по времени).

**Ситуация 2:**

```
Dim aTimer As System.Timers.Timer

'   Создаем таймер с интервалом в зависимости от настроек
aTimer = New System.Timers.Timer(Me.delay)

'   Биндим процедуру вызова таймером через определенные интервалы 
AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent
aTimer.Enabled = True

Private Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
' тут http вызовы с последующей записью в базу а также метод 
' который отображал срабатывания тика таймера, что так же приводит к 
' проблеме из ситуации №1

End Sub
```

Подскажите как лучше решить данную проблему, то есть, отобразить визуально тик таймера не вызвав рассинхронизацию по частоте вызова процедуры которая идет ниже по коду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ - 2 таймера.

1й таймер вызывает необходимые действия, меняет цвет, например у `Label`, и активирует второй таймер.

2й таймер через заданный интервал меняет цвет `Label` обратно и отключается, до повторной активации.

При этом интервал первого таймера должен быть больше интервала второго.

Второй вариант - сделать собственный контрол-мигалку с таймером внутри и настройками. Разместить его на форме и просто дергать этот контрол основным таймером приложения. Второй вариант требует больше кода, но позволяет повторно использовать мигалку там, где потребуется.